# Can someone look over an answer I gave?

Tags: discussion

@JanHudec (I just noticed you were on, sorry for bugging you) or anyone else, Could you look at the answer I gave to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19410/8730) and correct anything that is off. I think I got the concept right but when I did the math the bank angles I came up with seemed a little high.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask someone to check an answer like this. I just don't want to give bad info. Adso not sure if it's appropriate to tag someone specific, but I was sure that person would know. If I'm being inappropriate feel free to berate me!

Comment: The primary place to address an answer is in its comments. Hopefully people that may know the answer will stop by, read your answer, and vote/comment as they see fit. If you would like to discuss it more directly, chat may be a better place than meta. That being said, I don't think it's necessarily inappropriate to ask it here.

Comment: @fooot I started to put it in the comments but decided i wanted to ask here if it was bad form. I expected people to comment on my answer but nobody did. Unfortunately i can rarely catch anybody in the chat room. And i do a lot of my SE browsing on the android app and i can't figure out how to get to chat in the app.

Comment: I think your answer makes it pretty clear that you are doing a rough calculation. Hopefully if it's wrong someone will point it out. At least that's how I deal with it on my answers. It seems to work at least sometimes. : )

Comment: For chat it appears the [app does not have it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262110/stackoverflow-chat-in-mobile-app) but will open it in a browser.

Comment: @fooot thx. Do u happen to know where i would go for questions/suggestions about the app? I've gotten to chat on here before by following somebody's link. Just can't remember where that link was

Comment: @fooot Ah, just saw your second comment. Thx agn

Answer (score 2):

If you want someone else to review an answer, I think the best way to do that would be to ask [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) for people to have a look.

Or, just wait and see if people comment on your answer or even edit/correct it directly. If your answer is a good and useful one but has a few minor problems then people tend to comment or edit; if it's completely wrong then it will usually be downvoted and perhaps even deleted. Either way, that's exactly how it's meant to work.